# Can't get value from Array

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why this can't grab a value from the array?

```
var state_tax= new Array();
state_tax["Alabama"]=0.05;
state_tax["Alaska"]=0;
state_tax["Arizona"]=0.08;
state_tax["Arkansas"]=0;
state_tax["Maryland"]=0.06;

var v_tax=0;

var lv_bts = 'Maryland'; 

var v_tax = state_tax[lv_bts.value];
```

Thanks

Comment: `lv_bts` is a string, it doesn`t have value propery.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot grab it since there's no `value` property in your `lv_bts`.
Also, why not using something that you can easily debug? Using Array (or actually it's *Object* instance) with named keys is **odd**. if you do say: `state_tax.length` a `0` result is just misleading and erroneous.

**Use an Object literal instead:**

```js
var state_tax = {
"Alabama" : 0.05,
"Alaska" : 0,
"Arizona" : 0.08,
"Arkansas" : 0,
"Maryland" : 0.06
}

console.log( state_tax.Maryland );
console.log( state_tax["Maryland"] );
```

If you do really want to have a `value` property, than here you go:

```js
var state_tax = {
"Alabama" : {value: 0.05},
"Alaska" : {value: 0},
"Arizona" : {value:  0.08},
"Arkansas" : {value: 0},
"Maryland" : {value: 0.06}
}

console.log( state_tax.Maryland.value );
console.log( state_tax["Maryland"].value );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need just the value of the string as key, without any property.

```
var v_tax = state_tax[lv_bts];
//                    ^^^^^^
```

You may use an object instead of an array, because you use it like an object, without using the special features of an array.

```js
var state_tax = {};
state_tax["Alabama"] = 0.05;
state_tax["Alaska"] = 0;
state_tax["Arizona"] = 0.08;
state_tax["Arkansas"] = 0;
state_tax["Maryland"] = 0.06;

var lv_bts = 'Maryland';
var v_tax = state_tax[lv_bts] || 0; // take a default value if property does not exists

console.log(v_tax);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great!  Can you help me with one more thing? I need to get that "var lv_bts =" "  with something like <?php echo $BILLTOSTATE;?>  But it doesn't work inside of a function.  tried to add BILLTOSTATE to global and grab inside func, but still no success

Comment: sorry, i can not help with php.